# Unable to setup jetpack on my site

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I tried debug mode disable all other plugins but still jetpack is not working on my site. I tried manipulating xmlrpc also. 
my Website is [Mazahub](https://mazahub.com) and exact error when i click on setup jetpack is 
http://prntscr.com/nbu49m

Exact Error message

> Error Details: The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site https://mazahub.com [IXR -32300: transport error: http_request_failed cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds]

Answer (score 0):

Is your web site publicly available? Do you have CURL enabled on your site?

Either situation might cause your issue.

If the above is not helpful, then provide more details in a comment to your question, or edit the question. Provide enough details so others will know exactly what you did, and what went wrong.